# How to Reverse Taxonomy Order

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy template, the items are being displayed in the default order, from newest to oldest post.

How would I change the custom taxonomy template to list the posts in the opposite order? Is there a function for this?

Comment: Can you share the part of the code that's displaying the posts? For most kinds of queries, you can set `'order' => 'DESC'` and that will put them in descending (reverse) order.

Comment: It's on a taxonomy template file, so the loop is just the standard.. "while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();" type of loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the `pre_get_posts` action. `pre_get_posts` fires after the query variable object is created, but before the actual query is run. So you won't suffer performance penalties by running multiple unnecessary queries.

In your `functions.php`:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','xx_taxnomy_query');
function xx_taxnomy_query($query) {
    if ($query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() && $query->is_tax('your_taxonomy')) {
        $query->set('order', 'asc');
        return;
    }
}
```